# NO Repeat of Background Image in CSS not working

Tags: html, css, background

I just tried out making a web page today and ran into a problem, looked everywhere to resolve the issue but didn't help please tell me what's I am doing wrong.

here is the HTML doc

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Astrology</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  
</head>
<body>
  <div class="mtl">
  </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the style.css

```
*
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: wheat;
  background-size: cover;
}
*.mtl
{
  
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("./images/mars_p.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: -1844px 1160px;
  

}
```

Here is the picture when I put `background-repeat: no-repeat;`

[image]

And here is the picture after removing `background-repeat: no-repeat;`

[image]

Tell me why this no-repeat is not working

Comment: the background-position is HUGE so the image is out of sight (only visible if it's repeated)

Comment: so you are saying that the possible solution is the reduce the image size

Comment: but i want full resolution of the image i don't want to lose the image resolution @Temani Afif

Comment: I am talking about the position, I never meant the size

Comment: i want to use the mars to position like this https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eDSs7la2A32zYXtpaLYuFMCdlMs3KzwR/view?usp=sharing

Comment: start by setting `background-position: 0 0;` and change slowly the value and you will understand what's happening

Comment: I thin I have first I have to crop the image and then use I should use it, will it work and also i tried what you said setting positions to 0 and then rising by 50px each time but still the image repeating because as i commented above the link i want to show only the half picture in top left corner

Comment: But still i want to rotate the image slowly when someone open the website it should look like the mars is slowly rotating.

Answer (score 0):

The `background-repeat: no-repeat;` is working just fine, the problem is with this line:

```css
background-position: -1844px 1160px;
```

The picture moves to bottom-left of the screen too far and cannot be seen. You can only see it when you set the image to repeat or fix the `background-position` property smaller.